# AWS Lightsail to external mySQL connections failing

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, external

I created a new instance (bitnami WordPress) in AWS Lightsail. Everything works fine. I am trying to connect to an external MySQL server (outside of AWS) from this Lightrail instance.

I am using the command:

`mysql -u user_name -h xx.xx.xx.xx -p`

Unfortunately, I am receiving this error message. I am unsure why the Lightrail instance resolves the external IP (outside of AWS) to the local Lightrail instance.

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user_name'@'ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)`

I have performed an extensive search and could not find any similar issues.

FWIW, I have tried to add `skip_name_resolve` to the `my.cnf` file in vain.

I hope someone has run into this situation and was able to find a solution.

I could open a ticket with AWS; however, given that I have a basic account, I cannot place any support calls with AWS. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: It may just be the case whatever provider you're using happens to use AWS EC2 to provide the service. You _are_ getting an access denied error message, which means you are successfully connecting/talking to a MySQL server... you're just not being allowed in because the username/password or some other auth issue. If you're using the root username and password, note that MySQL doesn't allow you to login as root from remote locations. You need to create a separate user for connecting remotely.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. There is a local MySQL instance on the same AWS EC2 where I am executing the MySQL command. However, the -h argument I provided points to a MySQL server outside AWS. What is puzzling is that the local MySQL server on the AWS EC2 instance is responding to my command despite a non-AWS public IP given at the command line. If it helps, the instance I am using is a WordPress/Bitnami image for AWS EC2.